# Installing Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with a blank dvd/cd/disk problems

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, system-installation, windows-vista

I would like to install the 32-bit version of Ubuntu 12.04 on my computer alongside windows Vista. I downloaded the ISO file from the Ubuntu website. Then I formatted my empty / blank disc, and dragged the ISO file from my downloads folder to my disk.

I assumed that was all I needed to do, but when I rebooted my computer and selected my disk from the boot menu, it just booted up Windows regularly.

How can I install Ubuntu on my computer alongside Windows Vista?

Answer (score 1):

If you look on your disc, does it contain your downloaded file ?

What you need to do is follow the instructions on http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows

For information on how to install Ubuntu alongside Windows, called **dual booting** following the instructions on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

Comment: Yes it contains my downloaded file, yet when I select it in my boot menu it still boots to Windows.

Comment: It should not contain you downloaded file, it is an image and should be burned accordingly. See instructions in the link above and the answer from user195877.

Answer (score 1):

Overall the mistake your making is that you don't just copy the file. I made this mistake to and it was really frusrating. You need to mount the iso and then burn it. I don't know how to do it on windows but i'm sure if you look it up you'll find how to mount things.

Answer (score 0):

First - you need to be sure your boot priority in your bios goes to the CD/DVD drive first. That is a bios setting. 
Second - you need to be sure you have correctly burned the iso image onto the CD/DVD - not just COPIED the iso file onto the disk. Think of the iso as an archive - a zip file if you will. BURNING the image you need means unzipping it and putting the contents on the CD/DVD.

Comment: The first point is actually mentioned in the question, selected my disk from boot menu.

Comment: Ok - good. Then it sounds like you need to check your CD burning process next. Ubuntu and other distros always give you some way to verify the download file. MD5 sum, or SHA sum, whichever. Make sure you do that before burning. Instead of drag-and-drop, you may need to open your burning utility and follow the menu choices to get it done.